# Azure AD REST API to check if MFA is enabled for a user

Tags: rest, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am able to execute a power shell command to check if mfa is enabled for a user.
is there an equivalent REST call to check if user has mfa enabled in Azure AD?

Comment: no option for that. The user entity does not have a property for MFA https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity

Comment: AFAIK, Azure AD Rest API doesn't expose a property to show whether MFA is enabled for a user .And if you have any idea or feedback about Azure, you can submit them from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently available in the Azure AD Graph API or the Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: hi, is there a way to do so now? 1 year later? I have found the android sdk but then it is not able to return back the callback urls for me to know if the account is mfa enabled or not, is there a way of achieving this? pls help.